# Minimax For Connect four doesn't return a value

Tags: python

When i run this program i get an error that MinimaxNode' object has no attribute 'value'

ConnectFour is an other class that initializes the board and marks the moves, checks if someone won, etc.
Utility just returns 2 points (it is still in progress)

The problem arises that in MinimaxPlayer in child.get_minimax_value as it puts an error that MinimaxNode' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: Please post the entire traceback error message. It should provide the sequence of statements that lead to the error.

Comment: Better yet, please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @unutbu give me one second, i kind of fixed it but the MinimaxPlayer puts chips only on the first column

Comment: @unutbu i don't know how can i post the SSCCE since the mistake can be anywhere and I have trouble finding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `get_minimax_value` is a method, `child.get_minimax_value` should be `child.get_minimax_value()`.

Without the parentheses, `child.get_minimax_value` represents a bound method, not the value returned by the method.

Thus, `child.get_minimax_value` never equals `v`, and the `if-clause` condition is False, and `col` never gets set.

Python would then raise an error when it reaches

```
board.ConnectFour.play_turn(self.playernum, col)
```

---

I think perhaps in `MinimaxPlayer.minimax` the indentation level for the `return v` statements should be outside the `for`-loops. Otherwise, the node's value would only depend on the first child in `node.children`.

```
def minimax(self, node, cur_depth):
    if cur_depth == self.ply_depth:
        u = self.utility.compute_utility(node, self.playernum)
        node.set_minimax_value(u)
        return u
    node.compute_children()
    if cur_depth % 2 == 0:
        v = float("-inf")
        for child in node.children:
            childval = self.minimax(child, cur_depth + 1)
            v = max(v, childval)
            node.set_minimax_value(v)
        return v
    if cur_depth % 2 != 0:
        v = float("inf")
        for child in node.children:
            childval = self.minimax(child, cur_depth + 1)
            v = min(v, childval)
            node.set_minimax_value(v)
        return v
```

But it is really hard to say without runnable code.

Comment: it actually is " get_minimax_value(self):return self.value" but now it says 'MinimaxNode' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: Okay, that sounds like progress, but you'll have to show us the code that defines `MinimaxNode` then.

Comment: I did, i don't see why it doesn't want to return the value

Comment: The definition refers to `self.value`. Python is raising an error, saying that the attribute `value` has not been defined. No where in the code you posted is there any mention of a `value` attribute.  Is `value` getting defined at all? That's what we need to see.

Comment: Okay -- `self.value` gets set when the `set_minimax_value` method is called. But that method does not appear to ever get called.

Comment: hmmm thats all I have for the minimax, First I go through and assign to nodes a minimax value and now I want to find the node to take that specific path

Comment: i do have set method, let me post it

Comment: Here is a good programming habit: whenever you define a class, set default values for **all** its attributes in the `__init__` method, or in your case, the `init_root` and `init_child` staticmethods. Set some default value for `node.value` there, so nowhere else in your code do you have to deal with the possibility that `self.value` is not yet set.

Comment: but I kind of was given this layout, and also if i add "value" into arguments in  init_root and init_child then it would change a lot of my code

Comment: Can you post a runnable example, I haven't been able to guess in what order (and with what arguments) these methods are getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Your output you see is simply because you print out the object `MinmaxNode`, which must not have a `__repr__` method set up.

Your error of "local variable 'col' referenced before assignment" is because you define `col` conditionally in your for loop but use it as an argument in `play_turn` regardless of whether it's been assigned.  You should check that `col` has been defined after running your `for` loop and before calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because it`s possible the following line runs before`col` is assigned

```
board.ConnectFour.play_turn(self.playernum, col)
```

The `col` value is only assigned within the body of the `for` loop.  The python interpreter sees that and concludes that in the case the loop body executes 0 times, or the `if` conditional never evaluates to true, then `col` won't be assigned.

You need to definitively assign col a value before the loop executes and check for that when calling `play_turns`

```
col = -1
for child in root.children
  ...
if col != -1: 
  board.ConnectFour.play_turn(self.playernum, col)
```

Comment: i just tried that and it looks like the for loop never changes the col number

Comment: @JackF have you tried stepping through with the debugger to see what the values are?